# Native GCP solution for automatically deploying IAM resources to projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to come up with a way in GCP to automatically deploy defined IAM roles, policies and policy bindings to selected GCP projects or all GCP projects.

I am aware that GCP organizations exist and that they can be used to define IAM resources in one place to have them inherited to child projects. However, organizations are not mandatory in GCP and some customers will be using the old structure where projects exist side by side without inheritance and not wanting to migrate to an organization.

One solution would be to create scripts which iterate over projects and create everything. However, a GCP native solution would be preferrable. Is there a GCP native way of deploying defined IAM resources like this - and possibly other project level configurations - to specific GCP projects or all projects which works regardless of whether the customer uses organizations or not and without iterating over projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to come up with a way in GCP to automatically deploy
> defined IAM roles, policies and policy bindings to selected GCP
> projects or all GCP projects.

Deployment tools use concise descriptions of resources called configuration files. These tools manage resource state, meaning you declare what you want and they make it so. They are not dynamic in that you do not say sometimes do X and sometimes do Y. You say do X to Y and if different make it Y.

Deployment tools are IaaC - Infrastructure as Code. The configuration files are the blueprint for your goal of "desired state". You write the configuration files and the tools know how to build the resources that match the desired state.

If your goal is dynamic configuration based upon inputs, conditionals, and/or external factors, IaaC based tools will fail to meet your goal.

For IaaC based tools, you have two well-supported options.

- Google Deployment Manager. This is an official Google product. This product is vendor-specific.
- Terraform Google Provider. Terraform is a HashiCorp product. The Google Provider is developed by Google.

I recommend choosing Terraform and the Google Provider. Terraform is cross-platform with most of the world supporting Terraform. Terraform is very easy to use, there are numerous training resources, example configurations, Internet guides, getting-started articles, and YouTube videos. I have written a few articles on Terraform with Google Cloud.

In your question, you mention writing scripts. That is possible, but I do not recommend that. For one-off configurations, using the Google Cloud CLI in a script is workable and sometimes necessary. The benefits of a deployment language, once mastered, are tremendous.

> without iterating over projects?

Unless you implement organizations, Google Cloud Projects are separate independent resources. Deployment tools are project-specific, meaning if you want to manage resources in more than one project, you must declare that in the deployment configuration. They do not iterate projects, you declare them.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, it covers all aspects of my problem and I appreciate it very much. It makes sense to me: If IAM changes are to be made in many different projects, the best ways seem to be Organizations or something like Terraform.